# Qemu: How can I get a Bash?

Tags: filesystems, qemu

I have a file system directory `file/` and a kernel file `zImage`. At first, I converted the file system directory to SquashFS format.

I used the following command for this:

```
mksquashfs file file.squashfs
```

Then I used the following command to run them using Qemu:

```shell
qemu-system-arm -M virt-2.9 -kernel zImage -netdev user,id=net1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net1 -drive file=file.squashfs,if=virtio,format=raw -append "root=/dev/vda"
```

But Bash was not shown to me.

[image]

Comment: hm, that's the qemu monitor in a separate window, as you specified when you stated you want the serial console on stdio. How do you know the kernel isn't running? Select your serial console and look at that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't have Bash in the console. Is my command for run qemu correct?

Comment: bash is totally irrelevant to this problem. Go back and look at the serial output.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Basically, I want to have a Bash by running this file system and kernel. I searched the internet and came across the above command. But in the console where I executed the command, the Bash was not received. Can you tell me the correct order?

Comment: Again, go to the terminal you typed in that command. Your command specified that the serial console of the emulated hardware connects to that. You should be seeing the boot messages there. **You** are the one picking the options for your qemu invocation there, you should be the one looking up what they mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I updated the image in question. I have not received any output in my terminal.

Comment: You're showing that the command you're running is actually very different to what you ask in the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I updated the question. If I made a mistake in executing the command, please help me.

Comment: Still not the same command in picture and your question. Don't have time to home your hand through this, currently.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, Updated

Comment: So, now the serial=stdio is fine. What views besides the qemu monitor can you pick in the View menu?

Comment: @MarcusMüller compatmonitor0, serial0, parallel0. Do you mean these sections in the view menu?